# Why are my <p> and <div> elements not obeying display: inline?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
<p id="p">blablabla</p>
<div id="d">zizizizi</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#demo {
    width: auto;
}
#p {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#d {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

I have created a JSBin for this to show the output:
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/fomocojerodo/1/edit)

I want this:

```
[blablabla]    [zizizizi]
```

Instead of that, it shows:

```
               [zizizizi]
[blablabla]
```

Does anyone know the reason for this? And how to fix this?

Comment: You have to float div left instead of right and reset margin: http://jsbin.com/ruvedetoxeqa/1/edit

Comment: Do you really need to float both elements? And what is the reason that you are explicitly setting a `width:auto` to `#demo`? http://jsbin.com/kanonariwuhi/3/edit

Answer (score 3):

The `<p>` has a default 1em margin which causes it to move down.

Also, the `display: inline` will have no effect, since it is overridden by the `float` style.

Comment: @HashemQolami Please don't rollback revisions that improve the answer.

Comment: @TylerH This revision also has some mistakes that may mislead viewers. Specifically this part `margin of 16px on all sides`

Comment: @HashemQolami Fixed. In the future, it would be better to fix such a minor typo than to completely rollback the edit.

Comment: These are just default margins which can vary from one browser to another, they are not necessarily 16px.

Comment: @Douglas Added a better explanation even though the default font-size for browsers is 16px.

Answer (score 0):

USe this 
css
set padding:0px; and margin:0px; in

```
#demo {width: auto;}
#p {float: left; 
display: inline;padding:0px; margin:0px;}
#d {float: right;
display: inline; margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, make both elements float:left

this will automatically add every consecutive element next in line.

Here is how I would do it

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
Content of box 1
</div>
<div class="box">
Content of box 2
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{ float:left; display:inline}
```

you can add width css property if you want to set the width of each object as well

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the floats and replace the `display:inline` with `display:inline-block`. Then remove default margins and you have elements properly aligned, you need only to add padding/margins as you wish:
 `#p, #d{display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:0; }`